# getting started with jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Im learning web programming and now i stuck with jquery datepicker. I need a full example/tutorial that consist of **step-by-step** guide how to :

1. Display the jquery datepicker
2. Use it
3. Get the user input

I have done many searching but all i get is the tutorials about "*how to modifiy it(with css)*". I need a more beginner-friendly tutorial (im just getting started with `jquery` and `AJAX`, but i know standard `javascript`).

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ?

Comment: This isn't that kind of site. You will come back here if you run into a specific problem when implementing your datepicker. You don't come here for an entire guide on using it.

Comment: See [demos and examples](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [API reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: @F4r-20 i have seen so many questions about guides/tutorials and questions like this is OK in this site. And how come i ask question about jquery when i even confuse of getting started?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Thanks, thats the first site appear in google, but i cant understand it. I really looking into a more beginner-friendly tutorial :D Thanks for your help

Comment: There's an entire jQuery documentation, for people who are getting *started*

Comment: @BlazeTama: That would be as simple as it would get. the API site has demos, samples and shows you the source code. If that is not simple enough there might be a general lack of understanding of JavaScript which might need to be aquired first? I'm not trying to be smart at all I'm merely pointing out some of the issues you will have if the code and samples are not enough on the API site itself.

Comment: Okay all, thanks for your help and sorry for my mistake, its my bad :D
Maybe i just too desperate for learning so much thing in web development (html css js jquery ajax php sql blablabla...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need an input field and then add the `jQuery` datepicker to it by calling the `datepicker` method:

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" />

 <script>
   $(function() {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
   });
 </script>
```

**$(function() { }**  indicates that it will call the `datepicker` method and attach it to the HTML input control `datepicker` once the `DOM` has loaded.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Thanks for your help :D Do i need to download the jquery UI locally or is it ok to just use the link?what is your suggestion? Thanks :D

Comment: @BlazeTama download it from: http://jqueryui.com/ - then reference the file in your HTML document.

Comment: Thanks Sir and sorry for my bad question(s) :D